# Unresolved dependency for new relic in typesafe activator

Tags: scala, repository, newrelic, typesafe-activator

I'm using typesafe activator *1.3.5 ui* and trying to add **new relic** monitoring. I've passed configuration but can't build project after enabling monitoring (I'm working via *ui*) because of unresolved dependency for **sbt-nr-play** which is declared in `./project/sbt-nr.sbt`.

Found the [similar problem](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/unable-to-install-on-play-2-3-8/24671) but it's solution doesn't work. My assumption is that repos http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/maven-ivy-snapshots/ and https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots are disabled and it's the cause of the problem.

Help if you've faced the same problem or know how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: I do have the same problem, the artifactoryonline repos went offline just this morning. I have not found a solution other then hoping that they come back online tomorrow or on monday. Though, I configured my local artifactory to cache any dependency from artifactoryonline in the future.